# How do I create an Android App Bundle using Android Studio, command line (first steps from Android instructions don't work, not fully explained)?

Tags: powershell, android-studio, command-line, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

Hello and thanks for helping me solve my problem! I ask for an easier way, as I am trying to figure it out without success in this tutorial https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle. So far, I only worked with the Google Play Console itself, did not create an application in a third-party service. I first tried to download the Android App Bundle using Android Studio as described in this article https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/building-your-first-app-bundle-bbcd228bf631, but the first step describes pressing buttons that are not on Android Studio Panel "In Android Studio, select“ Build => Generate Signed Bundle / APK ”and follow the dialog." I do not see the options I need in the Android Studio panel (I attach a screenshot)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIa4P.png)
, where do I need to click to create an Android App Bundle? Then I tried to create the Android App Bundle from this tutorial using the command line https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline, I installed Grable manually as described in this tutorial https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html#installation unpacked and configured the system environment, as well as installed and unpacked JDK 17 for Windows/x64 (also on disk C but in a different non-Grable folder), but verifying the Grable installation when typing gradle -v in Windows PowerShell throws an error, and these instructions https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/troubleshooting.html#sec:troubleshooting_installation does not offer a solution what is displayed in my Windows PowerShell [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ocuo.png)
(The sentence highlighted in red from the screenshot in English looks like this "grable: The name grable is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, as well as the presence and correctness of the path, and then try again."), and when I enter gradle -v into the command line, it says "Grable is not an internal or external command, an executable program or a batch file.", I face the same problem if I enter into command line ./gradlew bundleRelease as suggested in this tutorial  https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/building-your-first-app-bundle-bbcd228bf631. I'm stumped, what am I doing wrong, and what method is easier for me to create an Android App Bundle? Thanks again for the help in solving my problem and I apologize in advance if I have provided little information necessary to solve my problem.

Comment: The error about `gradle` means it's not in path and Powershell doesn't know where to look for it. Use full path, e.g. `c:\program files\gradle` insead.

Comment: @vonPryz Windows PowerShell still throws the same error whether I enter the full path c:\grable, c:\grable ❯ gradle -v, c:\grable❯ gradle -v or c:\grable❯gradle -v ( I do not fully understand how to enter the full path). What other ideas are there for a method to solve my problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.